# Check if it's an homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

### **I'm posting this question since what I've come up sounds twisted!**

> Check if $g: S_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ is an homomorfism, given that
>   $$g(id)=0,\ g(12)=1,\ g(13)=1,\ g(23)=1,\ g(123)=0,\ g(132)=0$$

We want to check if $g(s_1 \circ s_2) = g(s_1) + g(s_2)$, where $s_1,s_2 \in S_3$.

Since I can't find a choice of $s_1,s_2$ such that the equality above is *not* satisfied, I go for a positive proof. Also, since $\circ$ is not commutative, $30$ cases should be tested. I decided to try to see some patterns.

Notice that if at least one between $s_1,s_2$ is the $id$ then the equality is trivially satisfied as
$$\text{lhs} = g(s_i \circ id) = g(s_i) = \text{rhs}$$

Also, each transposition is mapped to $1$.

Thus the cases left are: two transpositions, a transposition and a 3-cycle, two 3-cycles.

I used two assumptions that I didn't prove but seemed true in $S_3$ (!):

1. if you compose two transpositions then you either get the $id$ permutation or a 3-cycle.
2. if you compose a transposition and a 3-cycle you'll get a transposition.

Now:

- if $s_1,s2$ are two transpositions then because of (1.) on the lhs the argument of $g$ is either the $id$ or a 3-cycle, both of which map to $0$; on the rhs you'll have the sum of two transpositions, i.e. $1 + 1 \equiv_2 0$.
- if $s_1, s_2$ are a transposition and a 3-cycle then because of (2.) you get a transposition, that $g$ maps to $1$. On the rhs, you'll have a $1 + 0$.
- if $s_1, s_2$ are both a 3-cycle, you'll have the $id$ permutation on the lhs, and on the rhs $0 + 0$

Is that correct? Does a simpler approach exist?

Comment: This is just the sign homomorphism (although it is more common to write $\mathbb{Z}_2$ multiplicatively in this case) which is known to be a homomorphism even in a more genral setting.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos I'm asked to prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have simplified things reasonably well.  To summarize your approach:

In $S_3$ you have 1 1-cycle, 3 2-cycles, and 2 3-cycles.  $g$ maps all of the 2-cycles to $1$ and maps everything else to $0$.

So what's the product of 2 2-cycles?  It is either a 3-cycle or a 1-cycle.  This means that $g$ is multiplicative on two cycles.  You can reason through the other cases similarly.  This should help speed up a brute force solution.